# Tensorflow model returning insane loss values

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm a bit of a beginner, so please bare with me. I have a regression model I'm trying to build. Right now I'm experimenting with a neural network, but I'm getting such extremely weird and exorbitant loss values that I don't know where to proceed from here.

Ultimately, I don't know what's really going wrong here. Am I choosing the wrong loss function? Should I be normalizing the labels as well? But if I do, doesn't that defeat the point of having a predicted value? My code is below.

```py
train_dataset = dataset.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0)
test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)

train_dataset.describe().transpose()
```

This returns the following:

[image: [table][1]]

With `'feat3'` being the value I want to predict, I separate it from the features like so.

```
train_features = train_dataset.copy() 
test_features = test_dataset.copy()

train_labels = train_features.pop('feat3') 
test_labels = test_features.pop('feat3')
```

Since the input features are on wildly different scales, I normalize the first layer.

```
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(np.array(train_features))
```

To check that my features are normalized, I run the following.

```
sample= np.array(train_features[:1])

with np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True):
  print('First example:', first)
  print()
  print('Normalized:', normalizer(sample).numpy())
```

Which prints the following.

```
First example: [[1.14e+05 2.03e-03 1.68e-04 2.68e-03 5.92e+07]
 [6.15e+03 1.28e-02 3.99e-03 6.11e-03 5.20e+07]
 [2.93e+05 3.58e-02 4.60e-03 2.23e-02 1.33e+08]
 [4.14e+06 4.57e-02 1.27e-02 5.27e-03 6.81e+07]
 [7.11e+04 2.54e-02 1.51e-03 1.03e-02 1.06e+08]
 [5.83e+04 1.96e-02 1.15e-03 3.88e-03 4.44e+07]
 [9.22e+04 4.43e-02 7.27e-03 1.78e-02 2.46e+08]
 [3.85e+04 3.05e-03 3.23e-03 6.31e-03 4.32e+07]
 [2.96e+04 5.34e-03 8.48e-03 1.45e-02 6.41e+07]
 [4.42e+06 1.77e-02 1.96e-03 8.83e-03 5.43e+07]]

Normalized: [[-0.2  -0.   -0.05 -0.95 -0.58]
 [-0.22 -0.   -0.04 -0.61 -0.74]
 [-0.17 -0.   -0.03  0.98  1.01]
 [ 0.51 -0.    0.01 -0.69 -0.39]
 [-0.21 -0.   -0.05 -0.2   0.44]
 [-0.21 -0.   -0.05 -0.83 -0.9 ]
 [-0.2  -0.   -0.02  0.54  3.47]
 [-0.21 -0.   -0.04 -0.59 -0.93]
 [-0.22 -0.   -0.01  0.21 -0.47]
 [ 0.56 -0.   -0.04 -0.34 -0.69]]
```

Now that my data is seemingly normalized, I can go about defining, compiling and running the model.

```
def build_and_compile_model(norm):
  model = keras.Sequential([
      norm,
      layers.Dense(5, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
                metrics=['mse']
                )
  return model

dnn_model = build_and_compile_model(normalizer)

%%time
history = dnn_model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    validation_split=0.2,
    epochs=100)
```

I ran this overnight just to get a feel for the model and what hyperparameters I should begin tweaking. However after 100 epochs I was getting loss values in the order of trillions. I forgot to save the loss graph itself, but I still have the data up to 88 epochs.

```
Epoch 1/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 196s 2ms/step - loss: 44331637407744.0000 - mse: 44331637407744.0000 - val_loss: 39456153272320.0000 - val_mse: 39456153272320.0000
Epoch 2/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 207s 2ms/step - loss: 39772068249600.0000 - mse: 39772068249600.0000 - val_loss: 34276091363328.0000 - val_mse: 34276091363328.0000
Epoch 3/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 208s 2ms/step - loss: 34089449029632.0000 - mse: 34089449029632.0000 - val_loss: 28933246418944.0000 - val_mse: 28933246418944.0000
Epoch 4/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 29220210212864.0000 - mse: 29220210212864.0000 - val_loss: 25191245676544.0000 - val_mse: 25191245676544.0000
Epoch 5/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 26195569672192.0000 - mse: 26195569672192.0000 - val_loss: 23218039554048.0000 - val_mse: 23218039554048.0000
Epoch 6/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 208s 2ms/step - loss: 24764137603072.0000 - mse: 24764137603072.0000 - val_loss: 22252087148544.0000 - val_mse: 22252087148544.0000
Epoch 7/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 24091406893056.0000 - mse: 24091406893056.0000 - val_loss: 21790831149056.0000 - val_mse: 21790831149056.0000
Epoch 8/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 194s 2ms/step - loss: 23749376081920.0000 - mse: 23749376081920.0000 - val_loss: 21535125405696.0000 - val_mse: 21535125405696.0000
Epoch 9/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 190s 2ms/step - loss: 23670355394560.0000 - mse: 23670355394560.0000 - val_loss: 21398787457024.0000 - val_mse: 21398787457024.0000
Epoch 10/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 192s 2ms/step - loss: 23671892606976.0000 - mse: 23671892606976.0000 - val_loss: 21302335242240.0000 - val_mse: 21302335242240.0000
Epoch 11/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 194s 2ms/step - loss: 23643107098624.0000 - mse: 23643107098624.0000 - val_loss: 21243665317888.0000 - val_mse: 21243665317888.0000
Epoch 12/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 204s 2ms/step - loss: 23688229421056.0000 - mse: 23688229421056.0000 - val_loss: 21195460182016.0000 - val_mse: 21195460182016.0000
Epoch 13/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 212s 2ms/step - loss: 23761615060992.0000 - mse: 23761615060992.0000 - val_loss: 21153892532224.0000 - val_mse: 21153892532224.0000
Epoch 14/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 206s 2ms/step - loss: 23789683343360.0000 - mse: 23789683343360.0000 - val_loss: 21122603024384.0000 - val_mse: 21122603024384.0000
Epoch 15/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 192s 2ms/step - loss: 23909405556736.0000 - mse: 23909405556736.0000 - val_loss: 21096086634496.0000 - val_mse: 21096086634496.0000
Epoch 16/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 194s 2ms/step - loss: 23928705646592.0000 - mse: 23928705646592.0000 - val_loss: 21078248259584.0000 - val_mse: 21078248259584.0000
Epoch 17/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 193s 2ms/step - loss: 24077070761984.0000 - mse: 24077070761984.0000 - val_loss: 21051369062400.0000 - val_mse: 21051369062400.0000
Epoch 18/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 205s 2ms/step - loss: 24119596810240.0000 - mse: 24119596810240.0000 - val_loss: 21031420952576.0000 - val_mse: 21031420952576.0000
Epoch 19/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 206s 2ms/step - loss: 24162437431296.0000 - mse: 24162437431296.0000 - val_loss: 21012636762112.0000 - val_mse: 21012636762112.0000
Epoch 20/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 206s 2ms/step - loss: 24269274742784.0000 - mse: 24269274742784.0000 - val_loss: 20997914755072.0000 - val_mse: 20997914755072.0000
Epoch 21/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 192s 2ms/step - loss: 24290604875776.0000 - mse: 24290604875776.0000 - val_loss: 20983572332544.0000 - val_mse: 20983572332544.0000
Epoch 22/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 203s 2ms/step - loss: 24282612629504.0000 - mse: 24282612629504.0000 - val_loss: 20971077500928.0000 - val_mse: 20971077500928.0000
Epoch 23/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 196s 2ms/step - loss: 24423753056256.0000 - mse: 24423753056256.0000 - val_loss: 20960094715904.0000 - val_mse: 20960094715904.0000
Epoch 24/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 199s 2ms/step - loss: 24412589916160.0000 - mse: 24412589916160.0000 - val_loss: 20954843447296.0000 - val_mse: 20954843447296.0000
Epoch 25/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 211s 2ms/step - loss: 24430778515456.0000 - mse: 24430778515456.0000 - val_loss: 20943279751168.0000 - val_mse: 20943279751168.0000
Epoch 26/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 207s 2ms/step - loss: 24548133044224.0000 - mse: 24548133044224.0000 - val_loss: 20933741903872.0000 - val_mse: 20933741903872.0000
Epoch 27/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 191s 2ms/step - loss: 24621415923712.0000 - mse: 24621415923712.0000 - val_loss: 20927658065920.0000 - val_mse: 20927658065920.0000
Epoch 28/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 207s 2ms/step - loss: 24642951577600.0000 - mse: 24642951577600.0000 - val_loss: 20920726978560.0000 - val_mse: 20920726978560.0000
Epoch 29/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 193s 2ms/step - loss: 24680431878144.0000 - mse: 24680431878144.0000 - val_loss: 20909855342592.0000 - val_mse: 20909855342592.0000
Epoch 30/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 206s 2ms/step - loss: 24765932765184.0000 - mse: 24765932765184.0000 - val_loss: 20906703323136.0000 - val_mse: 20906703323136.0000
Epoch 31/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 208s 2ms/step - loss: 24757271527424.0000 - mse: 24757271527424.0000 - val_loss: 20900936155136.0000 - val_mse: 20900936155136.0000
Epoch 32/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 194s 2ms/step - loss: 24902897762304.0000 - mse: 24902897762304.0000 - val_loss: 20899516383232.0000 - val_mse: 20899516383232.0000
Epoch 33/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 198s 2ms/step - loss: 24909306658816.0000 - mse: 24909306658816.0000 - val_loss: 20894724390912.0000 - val_mse: 20894724390912.0000
Epoch 34/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 196s 2ms/step - loss: 25056679821312.0000 - mse: 25056679821312.0000 - val_loss: 20890483949568.0000 - val_mse: 20890483949568.0000
Epoch 35/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 208s 2ms/step - loss: 25119248351232.0000 - mse: 25119248351232.0000 - val_loss: 20887191420928.0000 - val_mse: 20887191420928.0000
Epoch 36/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 194s 2ms/step - loss: 25132552683520.0000 - mse: 25132552683520.0000 - val_loss: 20879035596800.0000 - val_mse: 20879035596800.0000
Epoch 37/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 206s 2ms/step - loss: 25170559369216.0000 - mse: 25170559369216.0000 - val_loss: 20873996140544.0000 - val_mse: 20873996140544.0000
Epoch 38/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 192s 2ms/step - loss: 25265470177280.0000 - mse: 25265470177280.0000 - val_loss: 20867916496896.0000 - val_mse: 20867916496896.0000
Epoch 39/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 207s 2ms/step - loss: 25264989929472.0000 - mse: 25264989929472.0000 - val_loss: 20863709609984.0000 - val_mse: 20863709609984.0000
Epoch 40/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 25348423024640.0000 - mse: 25348423024640.0000 - val_loss: 20861759258624.0000 - val_mse: 20861759258624.0000
Epoch 41/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 209s 2ms/step - loss: 25412491018240.0000 - mse: 25412491018240.0000 - val_loss: 20857766281216.0000 - val_mse: 20857766281216.0000
Epoch 42/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 199s 2ms/step - loss: 25512021852160.0000 - mse: 25512021852160.0000 - val_loss: 20854872211456.0000 - val_mse: 20854872211456.0000
Epoch 43/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 25598890082304.0000 - mse: 25598890082304.0000 - val_loss: 20849725800448.0000 - val_mse: 20849725800448.0000
Epoch 44/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 196s 2ms/step - loss: 25732170383360.0000 - mse: 25732170383360.0000 - val_loss: 20846942879744.0000 - val_mse: 20846942879744.0000
Epoch 45/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 193s 2ms/step - loss: 25751533387776.0000 - mse: 25751533387776.0000 - val_loss: 20848471703552.0000 - val_mse: 20848471703552.0000
Epoch 46/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 207s 2ms/step - loss: 25765856935936.0000 - mse: 25765856935936.0000 - val_loss: 20843090411520.0000 - val_mse: 20843090411520.0000
Epoch 47/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 207s 2ms/step - loss: 25792130056192.0000 - mse: 25792130056192.0000 - val_loss: 20838149521408.0000 - val_mse: 20838149521408.0000
Epoch 48/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 194s 2ms/step - loss: 25951161286656.0000 - mse: 25951161286656.0000 - val_loss: 20832870989824.0000 - val_mse: 20832870989824.0000
Epoch 49/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 194s 2ms/step - loss: 25963471568896.0000 - mse: 25963471568896.0000 - val_loss: 20832283787264.0000 - val_mse: 20832283787264.0000
Epoch 50/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 196s 2ms/step - loss: 25974301261824.0000 - mse: 25974301261824.0000 - val_loss: 20828200632320.0000 - val_mse: 20828200632320.0000
Epoch 51/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 196s 2ms/step - loss: 26060473237504.0000 - mse: 26060473237504.0000 - val_loss: 20823372988416.0000 - val_mse: 20823372988416.0000
Epoch 52/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 197s 2ms/step - loss: 26134473342976.0000 - mse: 26134473342976.0000 - val_loss: 20822076948480.0000 - val_mse: 20822076948480.0000
Epoch 53/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 197s 2ms/step - loss: 26234692042752.0000 - mse: 26234692042752.0000 - val_loss: 20822242623488.0000 - val_mse: 20822242623488.0000
Epoch 54/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 195s 2ms/step - loss: 26303067586560.0000 - mse: 26303067586560.0000 - val_loss: 20822666248192.0000 - val_mse: 20822666248192.0000
Epoch 55/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 26345499262976.0000 - mse: 26345499262976.0000 - val_loss: 20819633766400.0000 - val_mse: 20819633766400.0000
Epoch 56/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 196s 2ms/step - loss: 26390021799936.0000 - mse: 26390021799936.0000 - val_loss: 20816423026688.0000 - val_mse: 20816423026688.0000
Epoch 57/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 209s 2ms/step - loss: 26469581455360.0000 - mse: 26469581455360.0000 - val_loss: 20814499938304.0000 - val_mse: 20814499938304.0000
Epoch 58/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 211s 2ms/step - loss: 26474497179648.0000 - mse: 26474497179648.0000 - val_loss: 20807568850944.0000 - val_mse: 20807568850944.0000
Epoch 59/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 26635640242176.0000 - mse: 26635640242176.0000 - val_loss: 20804022566912.0000 - val_mse: 20804022566912.0000
Epoch 60/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 213s 2ms/step - loss: 26638435745792.0000 - mse: 26638435745792.0000 - val_loss: 20800539197440.0000 - val_mse: 20800539197440.0000
Epoch 61/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 197s 2ms/step - loss: 26767163129856.0000 - mse: 26767163129856.0000 - val_loss: 20797150199808.0000 - val_mse: 20797150199808.0000
Epoch 62/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 209s 2ms/step - loss: 26794650501120.0000 - mse: 26794650501120.0000 - val_loss: 20796504276992.0000 - val_mse: 20796504276992.0000
Epoch 63/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 194s 2ms/step - loss: 26790317785088.0000 - mse: 26790317785088.0000 - val_loss: 20794138689536.0000 - val_mse: 20794138689536.0000
Epoch 64/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 207s 2ms/step - loss: 26820076371968.0000 - mse: 26820076371968.0000 - val_loss: 20793838796800.0000 - val_mse: 20793838796800.0000
Epoch 65/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 208s 2ms/step - loss: 26943179194368.0000 - mse: 26943179194368.0000 - val_loss: 20792614060032.0000 - val_mse: 20792614060032.0000
Epoch 66/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 209s 2ms/step - loss: 27034690519040.0000 - mse: 27034690519040.0000 - val_loss: 20791232036864.0000 - val_mse: 20791232036864.0000
Epoch 67/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 198s 2ms/step - loss: 27094872489984.0000 - mse: 27094872489984.0000 - val_loss: 20788163903488.0000 - val_mse: 20788163903488.0000
Epoch 68/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 27150113570816.0000 - mse: 27150113570816.0000 - val_loss: 20785217404928.0000 - val_mse: 20785217404928.0000
Epoch 69/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 215s 2ms/step - loss: 27170577580032.0000 - mse: 27170577580032.0000 - val_loss: 20782749057024.0000 - val_mse: 20782749057024.0000
Epoch 70/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 201s 2ms/step - loss: 27200162103296.0000 - mse: 27200162103296.0000 - val_loss: 20779372642304.0000 - val_mse: 20779372642304.0000
Epoch 71/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 212s 2ms/step - loss: 27310663139328.0000 - mse: 27310663139328.0000 - val_loss: 20777302753280.0000 - val_mse: 20777302753280.0000
Epoch 72/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 27276324372480.0000 - mse: 27276324372480.0000 - val_loss: 20774970720256.0000 - val_mse: 20774970720256.0000
Epoch 73/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 196s 2ms/step - loss: 27305327984640.0000 - mse: 27305327984640.0000 - val_loss: 20774972817408.0000 - val_mse: 20774972817408.0000
Epoch 74/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 208s 2ms/step - loss: 27356838232064.0000 - mse: 27356838232064.0000 - val_loss: 20771579625472.0000 - val_mse: 20771579625472.0000
Epoch 75/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 199s 2ms/step - loss: 27469514014720.0000 - mse: 27469514014720.0000 - val_loss: 20768243056640.0000 - val_mse: 20768243056640.0000
Epoch 76/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 214s 2ms/step - loss: 27585348108288.0000 - mse: 27585348108288.0000 - val_loss: 20768641515520.0000 - val_mse: 20768641515520.0000
Epoch 77/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 211s 2ms/step - loss: 27720192884736.0000 - mse: 27720192884736.0000 - val_loss: 20766779244544.0000 - val_mse: 20766779244544.0000
Epoch 78/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 202s 2ms/step - loss: 27763480199168.0000 - mse: 27763480199168.0000 - val_loss: 20763958575104.0000 - val_mse: 20763958575104.0000
Epoch 79/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 212s 2ms/step - loss: 27823546826752.0000 - mse: 27823546826752.0000 - val_loss: 20762652049408.0000 - val_mse: 20762652049408.0000
Epoch 80/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 27889193975808.0000 - mse: 27889193975808.0000 - val_loss: 20763419607040.0000 - val_mse: 20763419607040.0000
Epoch 81/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 27935513772032.0000 - mse: 27935513772032.0000 - val_loss: 20758323527680.0000 - val_mse: 20758323527680.0000
Epoch 82/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 209s 2ms/step - loss: 27935505383424.0000 - mse: 27935505383424.0000 - val_loss: 20757165899776.0000 - val_mse: 20757165899776.0000
Epoch 83/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 196s 2ms/step - loss: 27985644093440.0000 - mse: 27985644093440.0000 - val_loss: 20755146342400.0000 - val_mse: 20755146342400.0000
Epoch 84/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 210s 2ms/step - loss: 28002886877184.0000 - mse: 28002886877184.0000 - val_loss: 20751805579264.0000 - val_mse: 20751805579264.0000
Epoch 85/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 198s 2ms/step - loss: 28104259010560.0000 - mse: 28104259010560.0000 - val_loss: 20749697941504.0000 - val_mse: 20749697941504.0000
Epoch 86/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 197s 2ms/step - loss: 28112161079296.0000 - mse: 28112161079296.0000 - val_loss: 20748796166144.0000 - val_mse: 20748796166144.0000
Epoch 87/100
97688/97688 [==============================] - 214s 2ms/step - loss: 28229131829248.0000 - mse: 28229131829248.0000 - val_loss: 20741556797440.0000 - val_mse: 20741556797440.0000
Epoch 88/100
95208/97688 [============================>.] - ETA: 4s - loss: 28422577324032.0000 - mse: 28422577324032.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's think why this might be happening given your data. Your model's initial predictions are likely to be rather small. The weights are initialized  to be small, and your `norm` layer squashes the inputs, so those are also small. We also know that at least one of your training labels is roughly `1e9`. If we only consider the loss of your model on this one training sample, your MSE should be roughly `1e9 ** 2 / |training set| = 1e18 / 4e6 = 1.5e11` or 150 billion. This loss value is so massive that the resulting gradients will also be gigantic, and your weights will be wildly fluctuating with each update.

You 100% can and should normalize your labels in this case. You can use the same method you used for your features. When you call `adapt` Your normalizer is going to calculate a `mean` and `variance` for your label column. When you want to get live predictions from your model after training, you can simply do `mean + variance * model(x)` to retrieve un-normalized predictions.

You should also be sure to evaluate the model on your test set while using the means and variances obtained from your *training data* to noramlize the test features and labels.

A last couple of other things to consider:

- The distributions of your training features and labels look more exponential than gaussian to me. You might want to `log` scale the features and labels before training.
- For tabular data like this, an ensemble method like Random Forest or XGBoost will probably outperform a DNN and be easy to implement out-of-the-box.
- With so few features and a tiny model like that, you shouldn't have to train for more than a couple of minutes, even with 4M training samples. Even 1 epoch is probably enough.

Comment: I first defined norm2 similar to how I did the features, except I changed the axis to None, since no other value worked. Then when I defined history, I replaced train_labels with norm2(train_labels). It's currently running, and I'm getting loss values < 1.0. I plan on trying random forest thanks to you, but am I on the right track so far?

Comment: Glad to hear that got the loss values under control! I trust they're also decreasing over time? After looking at the TF documentation, I believe setting `axis=None` in the Normalization layer is correct since you're inputting a 1D tensor of scalars. Doing RF next sounds good to me, too.